# Get rsync daemon module uid and gid

Tags: linux, daemon, rsync

I have a few rysnc modules setup in **/etc/rsyncd.conf** file on a server like this:

```
[build]
    path = /some/path
    read only = no
    uid = test
    gid = test
    comment = software Build area

[build_test]
    path = /some/other/path
    read only = no
    uid = test1
    gid = test1
    comment = software Build test area
```

I am able to get the list of all the rsync modules setup on the server with following command:

```
>>> rsync server_ip::
build           software Build area
build_test      software Build test area
```

This command returns jobs' names and associated comments only. How can I get the uids and gids of the modules as well. Is there any command for that?

**Update:**
More details can be found at: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-setup-the-rsync-daemon-on-linux

Comment: have you tried `ps aux | grep rsync` ?

Comment: There's no mechanism for determining this from the client side. What are you trying to do with this information?

Comment: Yes, after some research I found out that uids and gids cannot be obtained with any command from client side like this. But contents of the file `rsyncd.conf` can be displayed to client side terminal using an automated process of log in using ssh along with `cat /etc/rsyncd.conf` command. Please see the answer to my own question below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**rsync server_ip::** Command returns list of rsync modules' names and comments present in **rsyncd.conf** file on the server to your local terminal without the need of ssh into that server. But for more details like uids and gids, command should be run to display **rsyncd.conf** file contents in that server after log in using ssh. And after some research I found out how this process can be automated in python.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.Popen("ssh user@host -i key.pem \"cat /etc/rsyncd.conf\"", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

And output looks like this:

```
>>> '[build]\n        path = /\n        read only = no\n        uid = 1\n        gid = 1\n        comment = software Build area\n\n[build_test]\n        path = /\n        read only = no\n        uid = 1\n        gid = 1\n        comment = software Build test area\n'
```

Which then can be formatted according to need.